# Injective and surjective function

Tags: calculus

Determine whether or not the following function is injective and/or surjective.

$$ f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$$

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}2x &: \text{if }x \text{ is an integer}\\
x &: \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

I was able to prove that the function was injective for both cases, $f(x)=2x$ and $f(x)=x$. I am having a harder time determining if it is also surjective. I want to say that it is not surjective since $3\in\mathbb R$ there is no $x\in\mathbb Z$ such that $2x=3$. Is that enough to say that the function is not surjective?

Comment: Yes, that is enough to show that $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Yep that's pretty much it. You of course need to show that $f$ is injective, not just the functions $x\mapsto 2x$ and $x\mapsto x$

Answer (score 3):

Is $f$ surjecitive ?
Your answer is correct  if  $f(x)=3$  then  $x=3$ and $x$ not integer   or  $2x=3$  and  $x$  integer. That is not possible.

Is $f$ injective ?
**Hint:** show that If for $x,y \in {\mathbb R}$,   $f(x)=f(y)$   then $x$ and $y$ are both integers or both are not integers.